# Power Pivot Data Model Compatibility Issues between Excel MS 365 and Excel 2016

Tags: powerquery, powerpivot, excel-2016, excel-365

i built a data model using Excel in MS Office 365 and get errors when refreshing the data model in Excel 2016. The model calculations still run perfectly in Excel 2016 (once the user clicks ok to all the errors) but the user receives a number of errors [one of the errors received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Awfkb.png) which prevent them from using the model easily.

The errors do not show up when running the model on a computer with an MS Office 365 version of Excel. Additionally, none of the computations are too complex for Excel 2016 or use formulas not available in Excel 2016. The data model shows the supposed errors but the calculations are still unaffected and the pivot tables refresh properly but the slicers no longer work and cause the same error to appear.

Has anyone experienced this before or have any idea what could be the cause?

The only way to prevent the errors in Excel 2016 is to open the data model immediately after opening the file before attempting to refresh. having the model open in the background appears to prevent the errors from occurring during refresh in some cases but not all cases. This method does not always work and there appears to be no rhyme or reason to when this method works and when it does not.